# Saber que button fue presionado C#

Tags: c#, botón, events

Hago una calculadora y quiero simplificar el codigo con el tema de los eventos al hacer click en un button
Para no tener un evento Click por cada boton realizar un solo evento y aignarlo a todos los buttony asi que me detecte que button fue presionado y coloque su texto correspondiente en el label

```
LblPantallaPrincipal.Text = this.Text.ToString();
```

Dentro de el evento Click de un button pero me asigna el texto del formulario

La idea es no tener el

```
LblPantallaPrincipal.Text = btn1.Text.ToString();
```

En cada button cambiando el btn2 - btn3 - btn4 y asi

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo? ya que tengo 10 botones y un evento por cada uno, quisiera todos funcionen con el mismo evento y en dicho evento colocar un switch que me indique que button fue

Comment: No creo que lo que pretendes hacer sea correcto(una cosa es que funcione y otra cosa es que tenga sentido). Cada botón tiene su propio código diferente al resto, como pretendes que un mismo evento o método o lo que sea tenga el código propio de cada botón, ese hipotético método sería enorme y rompería con el principio de alta cohesión

Comment: Seria un código sencillo por lo que quise ver si había un modo de hacerlo...

Ya que el boton solo colocaria el valor de su texto a un label, en vez de tener 10 botones con el codigo 
     .Text.ToString();
Tener un solo evento para dichos botones

Answer (score 2):

Podrías obtenerlo de los parámetros del mismo evento:

```cs
private void onClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   var btn = (Button)sender;
   LblPantallaPrincipal.Text = btn.Text.ToString();
}
```

Si tienes que realizar lógica más complicada:

```cs
private void onClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   var btn = (Button)sender;
   switch (btn.Name) 
   {
        case "button1":
            ...
            break;
        case "button2":
            ...
            break;
        case "button3":
            ...
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que en el caso de que sean muchísimos más botones, el switch se vuelve inmantenible. En ese caso, quizá herencia y polimorfismo serian la opción a elegir pero depende totalmente de tu problema a resolver.

Comment: No puedo colocar el "btn" ya que no es un objeto tengo que colocar el objeto en ese caso el button (btn1 al 9) y si coloco e button como tal me va a colocar el texto del mismo...

Comment: @Javier Gonzalez ¿al menos probaste la respuesta de @Carlos antes de decir que no se puede?. Te recomiendo investigar qué es el `sender` en un evento y el significado de la instrucción `var btn = (Button)sender;`

Comment: Esta solución no es óptima y si fueran 100 botones, harias un Switch con 100 cases y si fueran 1000?

Comment: En caso de ser tantos botones si seria un problema, pero siendo 10 como en mi caso serviría, la cosa es que en C# debo declarar la variable en un tipo especifico, ejemplo un entero o flotante o string y me lo indicaron en Java asi que ahi no lo supe aplicar...

Puede que no entienda alguna cosas soy bastante nuevo

Comment: @JavierGonzalez, a la larga eso va a ser un dolor de cabeza

Comment: @Japv en el caso de muchos botones el performance y la mantenibilidad sí sería un problema. En ese caso, habría que analizar la lógica requerida por cada uno de los botones, si grupos de botones comparten la misma lógica, etc. lo cual está fuera del scope de la pregunta por lo que me limité a responder lo que se pidió.

Comment: Como puedo pasar el ejemplo ese que me indicaste a C#?